# Can't find variable: navigation - react-native - Tried trawling stack overflow can't find a fix

Tags: react-native

Having an issue with an app I'm developing,

Trying to use react navigation.

The app has a built in web-view and can be navigated (it's a wordpress site) - and the idea is when I hit the home button it should reset the app - I will be adding extra screens like settings etc

but I get:  `Can't find variable: navigation`

Here is the code (I've omitted some sensitive data)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
 import {
   NativeModules,
   SafeAreaView,
   StyleSheet,
   ActivityIndicator,
   View,
   Platform,
   TouchableOpacity,
   Text,
   StatusBar,
   Image
 } from 'react-native';
 
 import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
 
 import BubblSdk from './BubblSdk';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
// import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';


const HomeScreen = () => {

    
 
  const secretCode = "***";
  
  //  BubblSdk.saveBubblId("TestDevice");
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    BubblSdk.initialize('https://api.bubbl.tech/api/','******');
  } else {
    NativeModules.BubblSdk.saveActivatedPayloadTitle('Messages');
    NativeModules.BubblSdk.initialize('https://api.bubbl.tech/api','*******');
  }
  
  messagesButtonHandler = () => {
    proccessCode2();
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BubblSdk.payloadActivity();
    } else {
      NativeModules.BubblSdk.displayActivatedPayloads();
    }
    resetCodes();
  }
  
  dataButtonHandler = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BubblSdk.dataActivity();
    } else {
      NativeModules.BubblSdk.displayDataPayloads();
    }
  }
  
  logButtonHandler = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BubblSdk.logsActivity();
    } else {
      NativeModules.BubblSdk.displayLogs();
    }
  }
  
  mapButtonHandler = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BubblSdk.mapActivity();
    }
  }
  
  var codes = "000";
  var code1 = 0;
  var code2 = 0;
  var code3 = 0;
  const [hide, setVisibile] = useState(Boolean);
  const onPress1 = () => proccessCode1();
  const onPress2 = () => proccessCode2();
  const onPress3 = () => proccessCode3();
  
  setCodes = () => {
    codes = code1+ "" + code2 + code3; 
    console.log("aanchal codes: "+ codes);
  }
  
  setCodes();
  
  resetCodes = () => {
    code1 = 0;
    code2 = 0;
    code3 = 0;
    setCodes();
      
    setVisibile(false);
  }
  
  proccessCodes = () => {
    setCodes();
    if (codes == secretCode) {
      setVisibile(true);
    } else {
      setVisibile(false);
    }
  }
  
  proccessCode1 = () => {
    code1 = code1 + 1;
    proccessCodes();
  }
  
  proccessCode2 = () => {
    code2 = code2 + 1;
    proccessCodes();
  }
  
  proccessCode3 = () => {
    code3 = code3 + 1;
    proccessCodes();
  }
  
  const myScript = `
    document.querySelector("#jp-post-flair").style.display="none";
    document.querySelector("#actionbar").style.display="none";
    document.querySelector("#colophon").style.display="none";
    true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
  `;
  
  const messageImage = require('./images/Imatter-icons-13.png');
  const homeImage = require('./images/Imatter-icons-14.png');
  
  
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' />
      
         <SafeAreaView style={styles.flexContainer}>
         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
             <WebView
             javaScriptEnabled={true}
             domStorageEnabled={true}
             injectedJavaScript={myScript}
             mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
             source={{
                 uri: 'https://*******.wordpress.com/',
             }}
             onMessage={(event) => {}}
             />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.tabBarContainer}>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={hide ? dataButtonHandler : onPress1}>
                 <Text style={hide ? styles.button : styles.codeButton}>{hide ? "Data" : "XXXXXX"}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
                 <Image style={styles.navImage} source={homeImage}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={messagesButtonHandler}>
                 <Image style={styles.navImage} source={messageImage}/>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={hide ? logButtonHandler : onPress3}>
                 <Text style={hide ? styles.button : styles.codeButton}>{hide ? "Logs" : "XXXXXX"}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
         </View>
         <View style={styles.tabBarContainer}>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
                 <Text style={styles.button}>Home</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={messagesButtonHandler}>
                 <Text style={styles.button}>Messages</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
             </View>
             <View style={styles.column}>
             </View>
         </View>
         </SafeAreaView>
     </>      
  );
  };



const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flexContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  tabBarContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  navImage: {
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  column: {
    width: '33%',
    alignContent: "space-between",
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 12
  },
  codeButton: {
    opacity: 0,
    fontSize: 12
  }
});


export default App;
```

I am taking on a project - I'm still learning react native

Comment: You need to pass in navigation as props like `const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {`

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but got: `ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.` - I've looked at the documentation :/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

firstly create folder in that folder create file HomeScreen.js paste ur all code on HomeScreen.js

```
 const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => { // your HomeScreen function code}
```

second import that file to the app.js

third on below code

```
return (
            <>
              <StatusBar barStyle='dark-content' />
              
                 <SafeAreaView style={styles.flexContainer}>
                 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                     <WebView
                     javaScriptEnabled={true}
                     domStorageEnabled={true}
                     injectedJavaScript={myScript}
                     mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
                     source={{
                         uri: 'https://*******.wordpress.com/',
                     }}
                     onMessage={(event) => {}}
                     />
                 </View>
                 <View style={styles.tabBarContainer}>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={hide ? dataButtonHandler : onPress1}>
                         <Text style={hide ? styles.button : styles.codeButton}>{hide ? "Data" : "XXXXXX"}</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>

 //  ur screen name should be used to navigate from one screen to another screen not a  component

    <Image style={styles.navImage} source={homeImage}/>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={messagesButtonHandler}>
                         <Image style={styles.navImage} source={messageImage}/>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={hide ? logButtonHandler : onPress3}>
                         <Text style={hide ? styles.button : styles.codeButton}>{hide ? "Logs" : "XXXXXX"}</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                 </View>
                 <View style={styles.tabBarContainer}>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                         <Text style={styles.button}>Home</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     <TouchableOpacity onPress={messagesButtonHandler}>
                         <Text style={styles.button}>Messages</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                     </View>
                     <View style={styles.column}>
                     </View>
                 </View>
                 </SafeAreaView>
             </>      
          );
          };
        
        
        
        const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
        
        const App = () => {
            return (
              <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
              </NavigationContainer>
            );
        }
        
        
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          flexContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column'
          },
          tabBarContainer: {
            padding: 10,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            backgroundColor: '#fff'
          },
          navImage: {
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          },
          column: {
            width: '33%',
            alignContent: "space-between",
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          },
          button: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: 12
          },
          codeButton: {
            opacity: 0,
            fontSize: 12
          }
        });
        
        
        export default App;
```

and another thing is that image source is working ? cause I am not seeing imported files at top ..thanks hope it will work.